# how does the .NET runtime CLR (written by C/C++) get compiled into clr.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

we know that CLR .net runtime is a plain dll called `clr.dll` can this dll file contains all the components that consists of .net runtime such as garbabe collector, so `clr.dll` must contains code related to garbage collector,

we also know that CLR is written by C/C++ as https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/coreclr/gc

so how can CLR be a dll file? isn't that dll files contains IL code(C# source code get compiled to), dll files don't contain C/C++ code, isn't it?

Comment: The other way around, it is the .dll file generated by the C# compiler that is the odd one.  It contains data, not machine code like a .dll normally contains.  Like clr.dll.  Turning that data into executable code is the job of the just-in-time compiler.

Comment: so does `clr.dll`  contains C/C++ code like this https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/coreclr/gc

Comment: It contains executable machine code.  Generated by a C++ compiler and linker from sources files like the ones you linked.

Comment: It is important to note that there are different types of dlls. Normal (i.e. native) dlls contain machine code. While .net dlls (i.e. assemblies) contain IL code. They are internally very different, even if the extension is the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CLR itself is considered a *native* DLL. It's written in C++ and compiled to native machine code. This *native* DLL is responsible for executing managed code by providing services like garbage collection, JIT compilation, etc.

When a .NET application starts, the operating system loads the native `clr.dll` into memory. This DLL then takes over the execution of the managed application, JIT compiling the IL code to native code, managing memory, and providing other runtime services.

More Info:

https://www.developer.com/microsoft/c-sharp/managed-unmanaged-native-what-kind-of-code-is-this/